# Is Apple's iPhone Retina Display really accurate to human eye resolution?

Tags: perception, vision, sensation, devices

Apple based their [Retina Display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4#Display) on the following claim, as cited by Wikipedia:

> The display has a contrast ratio of 800:1. The screen is marketed by Apple as the "Retina Display", based on the assertion that a display of approximately 300 ppi at a distance of 12 inches (305 mm) from one's eye, or 57 arcseconds per pixel is the maximum amount of detail that the human retina can perceive.

However some have stated that the resolution of the human retina is *significantly* higher than Apple's claim:

> Soneira stated that the resolution of the human retina is higher than claimed by Apple, working out to 477 ppi at 12 inches (305 mm) from the eyes, or 36 arcseconds per pixel.[44]

My impression of the human eye's "resolution" has been that it's significantly higher than the "Retina" display.

Is there any objective evidence that supports or refutes Apple's claim that the Retina display matches human eye resolution? Have any studies specifically been done to determine whether humans can differentiate "Retina" displays and higher resolution displays at the same distance?

Answer (score 5):

Until peer-reviewed data on the topic is published, all we have to go on is blog posts from vision and display researchers. The best posts I've seen so far are:

> - Artal, P. (2012) [Is the display resolution of the new iPad adequate for the eye?](http://pabloartal.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/is-display-resolution-of-new-ipad.html)
> - Artal, P. (2012) [What have in common the Apple “Retina” display and our retina? Probably, only the name.](http://pabloartal.blogspot.com/2012/04/what-have-in-common-apple-retina.html)
> - Soneira, R.M. (2012) [New iPad Display Technology Shoot-Out](http://www.displaymate.com/iPad_ShootOut_1.htm)

To summarize: Some people can see the difference in some cases.